# Using a continuous alpha in geom_hex (dropped aesthetics: alpha)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot some points using `geom_hex` while using a continuous variable as the alpha value for any given observation. However, I am returned with:

```
Warning message:
The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation:
alpha
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping
  structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical
  variable into a factor?
```

This is failing for even a simple 5-row reprex. Converting to a factor obviously defeats the purpose of using a continuous alpha. This is my data and code:

```
 tibble(
  x = c(38.8, 27.8875, 32.7375, 47.2875, 25.4625),
  y = c(42, 35.7, 35.7, 31.5, 39.9),
  name = rep('John', 5),
  percentile = c(0.934, 0.932, 0.883, 0.806, 0.2)
) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, alpha = percentile)) +
  geom_hex()
```

I can get around this by creating the fill values myself with something like:

```
data |>
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(fill = adjustcolor('#464D77', alpha.f = percentile)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_hex() +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

Though, I'd much rather use `alpha` and not need to mess with `rowwise`.

My `ggplot` syntax looks normal, and something like this would work with other `geoms`. Is there a special case for `geom_hex` that I am overlooking?

Comment: Hm, strange. I don't know why this happens, but it does work if you add `group` to your `aes`. If I had to guess, I think it might be because goem_hex does some kind of density plot calculations, where multiple, overlapping "points" are combined, with the desnity of values contributing to color or alpha or something. So it can't just assume that each X-Y value is a separate plotting entity unless you tell it that. If you just add a `grp` variable to your data.frame (here it could just be the row_number) and then add `group=grp` to your aes, it will work

Comment: You need an alpha value per bin, not per data point.  Even if your example has one point per bin, it's not guaranteed.  What's your intention if more than one point falls in a bin - what should the alpha be?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen that would not happen. There will not be multiple observations per x and y coordinates. The data originates from a `summarize` calculation that is grouped for both x and y (as well as name).